# Spark groupBy aggregation result joined back to the initial data frame

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I realize that I am often tempted to do the following:

```
var df_mean  = df.groupBy("category").agg(mean("column1") as "mean")
val df_with_mean = df.join(df_mean, Seq("category"))
```

So basically I want all the rows of my initial dataframe to have a column which is the mean value of their category.

Is it the correct way to achieve that? Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct (yields expected results) and idiomatic. `DataFrame` DSL is just a wrapper around SQL and standard SQL solution can be expressed as follows:

```
WITH means AS (SELECT category, avg(column1) AS mean FROM df GROUP BY category)
SELECT df.category, df.column1, means.mean
FROM df JOIN means ON df.category = means.category
```

You can easily check that this generates the same execution plan as `df_with_mean`.

It is possible to express the same logic using window functions:

```
SELECT *, avg(column1) OVER w AS mean FROM df
WINDOW w AS (
    PARTITION BY category
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
```

with DSL equivalent:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"category").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)

df.select($"*", avg($"column1").over(w).alias("mean"))
```

but in general Spark doesn't perform particularly well with `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` frame.